# Accessing CMS collection in Apex or via API

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community

Is it possible to access CMS collections in Apex or via API? I am am looking to build a custom CMS collection component which would have more functionality than the standard component.

I would prefer to use collections but from what I can see the only way to get filtered content would be to use topics and get the data as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedContent_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedContent_static_methods.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with the Salesforce team that owns this feature and confirmed that it is not exposed through any API. This feature is not listed in the [Metadata Coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/51) too.